# Why does it display the wrong date in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

Note: Please don't mark this as duplicate This is not related to other questions as they all have incorrect timezone while I don't and the time getting displayed is literally January 01, 1970, 05:00:00 although it is May 19, 2020, 12:19:00 right now.

I am using the PHP date function for this

```
<?PHP

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");

    // Converting $timestamp to human readable format
    $date = date("F d, Y h:i:s", $timestamp);

?>
```

Comment: So you never set any value to `$timestamp`? Why do you expect it to give the current time?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Sorry, I could not quite get what you are trying to say.

Comment: `$timestamp` is __not defined__. Now you get?

Comment: @u-mulder thanks I have fixed it by putting $timestamp = time(); and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't include `$timestamp` it will give you the current date, which is what you want I assume:

```
$date = date("F d, Y h:i:s");
```

See [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more details.

Comment: thanks, I just added $timestamp = time(); in my code and it worked.